# AngularJS UI-Router flickering during reroute

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-router

I have AngularJS ui-router, and am checking the state of authentication during state changes. During this change, I am experiencing a flicker as AngularJS resolves the promise of whether it should present that page. For example, if a user is logged in, /#/ is protected and redirects to /#/home. However, I see a brief glimpse of /#/'s html and then the redirect happens. How can I block this flicker from happening?

```
    function authenticate($q, $state, $timeout, AuthService) {
    AuthService.isLoggedIn()
        .then(function () {
            // Resolve the promise successfully
            console.log("auth")
            return $q.when()
        })
        .catch(function () {

            $timeout(function () {
                // This code runs after the authentication promise has been rejected.
                // Go to the log-in page
                $state.go('main')
            })

            // Reject the authentication promise to prevent the state from loading
            return $q.reject()
        })


}

function notAuthenticate($q, $state, $timeout, AuthService) {
    AuthService.shouldNotBeLoggedIn()
        .then(function () {
            // Resolve the promise successfully
            console.log("not auth")
            return $q.when()

        }).catch(function () {

            $timeout(function () {
                // This code runs after the authentication promise has been rejected.
                // Go to the log-in page
                $state.go('home')
            })
            // Reject the authentication promise to prevent the state from loading
            return $q.reject()

        })

}

/** @ngInject */
function routeConfig($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {
    $stateProvider
        .state('home', {
            url: '/home',
            templateUrl: 'app/home/home.html',
            controller: 'HomeController',
            controllerAs: 'home',
            resolve: {authenticate: authenticate}
        })

        .state('main', {
            url: '/',
            templateUrl: 'app/main/main.html',
            controller: 'MainController',
            controllerAs: 'main',
            resolve: {notAuthenticate: notAuthenticate}
        })
```

Comment: Your "resolves" resolve immediately, because neither `authenticate` nor `notAuthenticate` functions return a promise. So, in case of `main` state, you successfully enter the state, only to be redirected a short moment later to `home`

Comment: @NewDev seems like `$timeout` is the the problem, it lands on the page from `.catch` function & redirecting in next digest..I'm not sure..

Comment: @NewDev thanks new dev. Your answer was correct. If you post it I'll award you the question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `resolve` of the state is intended to "resolve" some injectables, before the state is activated. So, the "resolves" (the properties of `resolve: {...}`) expect a function that either return a value or a promise of a value. In case of authentication, it could be the `user`.

In your case, the resolve functions do not `return` a promise - they just run and complete immediately, thus activating the state. Then, *some (short) time later*, your `AuthService` kicks in and decides to change the state. This causes the flickering.

```
function authenticate($q, $state, $timeout, AuthService) {

   // this "return" is what returns the promise
   return AuthService.isLoggedIn()
                     .then(....);
}
```